# Parallel execution of algorithm in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm

I want to run X **independent** calculations in Java. Basically I should run some algorithm on different data sets. So, to save time, I'd like to run it in parallel.
My laptop has 2 cores 2.30MHz processor with 8GB RAM. Do I understand correctly that the best option would be to create 2 Threads (since I only have 2 cores)? Do I need to use some specific library (excluding more complicated approaches like Hadoop)? For instance [ParJava](http://panda.ispras.ru/~javap/parallel_java/par_java/parjava.html).
Or simple Threads would be enough?

**Update:**

```
        List<Integer> solutions= new ArrayList<>();
        IntStream.range(0, NumIterations).forEach( i ->
            solutions.add(
                    runAlgorithm();
            )
        );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do I understand correctly that the best option would be to create 2 Threads (since I only have 2 cores)?

Possibly. If you have hyperthreading you might have 4 logical CPUs.  The optimal number might be higher depending on what you are doing.

> Do I need to use some specific library (excluding more complicated approaches like Hadoop)?

Again, it depends, but there is 4 different libraries in the JDK already. I would try one of those first. e.g. try Stream's `parallelStream`

> For instance ParJava. Or simple Threads would be enough?

I would try using one of the higher level libraries to make you life easier.

For the example above you would do...

```
List<Integer> solutions = IntStream.range(0, NumIterations)
        .parallel()
        .map( i -> runAlgorithm(i))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This uses an optimised thread pool to split out the work and collect the results.

Comment: Does `parallelStream` work with Java 7?

Comment: @KlausosKlausos You need Java 8. Java 7 is no longer publically supported

Comment: See my Update. Do you mean something like this? In this case where should I define the number of parallel processes?

Comment: @KlausosKlausos I have added an example.  The stream's libraries attempts to optimise the number of threads to use.